# How do dynamically set group by properties and aggregates in a LINQ query?

Tags: linq

I assume I need to use the method call syntax instead of the query expression form, and I know the basics of grouping in the latter.  Maybe some gurus can give caveats and advice on using group fields and aggregates obtained at runtime from a configuration, for use in a reporting like structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you looked at Dynamic Linq?  It should do what you want.  Have a look at this [post](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/01/07/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library.aspx) from scottgu's blog.

Answer (score 0):

If your data is in xml, linq to xml would allow you to write queries against it in which the certain inputs are strings.

For example:

```
System.Xml.Linq.XElement myData = GetData();

System.Xml.Linq.XElement result = new XElement("Result",
  myData.Elements("Customer")
  .GroupBy(e => e.Attributes("Name"))
  .Select(g => new XElement("CustomerResult",
     new XAttribute("Name" = g.Key,
     new XAttribute("Count" = g.Count(),
     new XAttribute("MinDate" = g.Min(e => e.Date)
  )
 );
```